# intent and onNewIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I've an app that has a main menu screen called NfcScannerActivity. At the moment it has no launch mode (standard) in the manifest. If you click on getRota it takes you to the rota screen which is defined in the manifest as 'singleTask' and is simply a listview of data from a webcall.

In the rota screen you can click on nextRota from the optionsMenu bar. When this happens, an intent is launched specifying the menu screen(NfcScannerActivity) as this is where the webcall is made to get the next day's rota data. once the data is retrieved the rota screen is launched again.

All this works fine but i'm convinced that there are some problems in the app due to having more than one instance of the menu screen in the task. If i specify NfcScannerActivity to be 'SingleTask' then when you click next rota it stays on the menu screen as if it hasn't handled the "NEXT_ROTA" intent action.

I understand that i might have to override onNewIntent in the NfcScannerActivity activity.

How is this done? I've tried the following.

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
    }
```

.

This doesn't seem to handle the 'NEXT_ROTA' intent action. thanks matt.

[edit1]

this is what i have in the rota activity when the user clicks next_rota from the options menu.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NfcscannerActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            i.putExtra("nextRota", nextDay);
            i.setAction("NEXT_ROTA");
            startActivity(i);
```

.

Then in the onCreate of NfcScannerActivity i have the following.

```
if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("NEXT_ROTA")){

            Log.e(TAG, "next rota action");
            String date = intent.getStringExtra("nextRota");



            getNextRota(date);


        }
```

.

getNextRota(date) calls an AsyncTask to make the webcall to get the data of the next rota. In the onPostExecute it the does the following.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(NfcscannerActivity.this,
                            GetRota.class);
             Bundle b = new Bundle();
             b.putSerializable("rotaArray", rotaArray);


             intent.putExtra("rotaArrayBundle", b);
             startActivity(intent);
```

.

So i'm already handling the 'NEXT_ROTA' intent action in NfcScannerActivity inside onCreate. Do i have to do the same in onNewIntent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

In the rota screen Activity when "an intent is launched specifying the menu screen"

```
Intent intent = new Intent(<rota screen activity>, NfcScannerActivity.class);
intent.setAction("NEXT_ROTA");
//this brings the previous existing activity to the front of the stack 
//instead of creating a new one
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the NfcScannerActivity

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    if(intent.getAction().equals( "NEXT_ROTA")){
        String date = intent.getStringExtra("nextRota");
        getNextRota(date);      
    }       
}
```

What the above should do is allow you create as many Rota Screens as you want but only ever have the one NfcScannerActivity

Comment: Yes you have to do the same in onNewIntent, onCreate isn't called when onNewIntent is called.